# #if usage with enums

Tags: c, if-statement, enums, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a header file with something like:

```
enum DataRate {
    AB0,
    AB1,
    AB2,
    ...
};
```

and in my code I have things like

```
#define S_FACTOR AB0
```

Now, function calls like

```
foo(S_FACTOR);
```

seem to work OK, but conditional compilations

```
#if ( (S_FACTOR == AB0) || (S_FACTOR == AB2) )
```

don't work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor knows nothing about enums; it is simply a manipulator of text. When you provide

```
#define S_FACTOR AB0
```

you are telling the preprocessor to substitute the token `S_FACTOR` with the token `AB0`, and nothing else.

The `#if` preprocessor directive is a bit of an oddity. It still does little more than textual substitution, with the intent of reducing its argument to an arithmetic expression involving integer constants. So it starts by replacing all defined macros in the expression. Then it replaces any remaining identifier token with 0, and attempts to evaluate the expression.

So

```
#if ( (S_FACTOR == AB0) || (S_FACTOR == AB2) )
```

will first be reduced to

```
#if ( (AB0 == AB0) || (AB0 == AB2) )
```

because `S_FACTOR` is a macro with a replacement list.

Then it replaces all identifiers with 0:

```
#if ( (0 == 0) || (0 == 0) )
```

That certainly evaluates to 1 (by the usual C semantics for boolean values), so the body of the `#if` is processed. But it would have been exactly the same had `S_FACTOR` been #defined as `AB1`.

There is a reason the preprocessor is called the *pre*processor. It does its work before any other processing, including declarations.

Comment: OK, I get it. If I want to use '#define' to set up conditional compilation, is there any other scheme than simply '#define SNA' and '#define FOO' so that later I can perform simple logic on them (as I have done)?

Comment: Hmm.. seems clear now I don't use an enum for this! (The enums I am using were provided to me in a .h file so I'll have to come up with something). **Thanks!**